# Is there a thing so-called integral over the projective line of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: integration, infinity, projective-geometry

In projective geometry, a line can be viewed by its projective line, which has only one point at infinity, and if a point keeps moving to $+\infty$ it will return to $-\infty$. On the other hand many integrals are taken over the real line. I wonder if there is a connection between two concepts. Would it be an integral over a circle or something? Would this be affect if the integral is replaced with a sum over $\mathbb Z$? I understand the function under integration is a member of $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$, and the series under summation is a member of $\mathbb R^\mathbb Z$

Comment: Yes from $[x:y ] \mapsto [y:x]$ you see the topology of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ is of a circle and you can define an  integral accordingly, for example with $\int_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})} f(u)du = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f([\tan x:1])dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is choosing a metric (alternatively, a measure) on the real projective line with respect to which the integration is to be performed.  It is natural to identify the real projective line with a circle in which case the natural metric is simply the least length of an arc joining the two points, i.e., the subtending angle $\theta$ in radians.

The way to define a distance between two points $A,B$ in the projective plane is to take the representing lines $a,b$ through the origin in the plane and set the distance between them be the angle between vectors $\alpha,\beta$ spanning $a,b$ respectively.  Thus one would set the distance between $A$ and $B$ to be $\arccos \alpha \cdot \beta$ where "$\cdot$" is the scalar product, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unit vectors.

Comment: Oh, so the model of projective line depends on how the metric is defined on it?

Comment: In projective geometry there is no distance; only relations of collinearity, concurrence, etc.  If you want to *integrate* you have to add an additional piece of information to the picture, namely the metric and/or measure. In some cases there are fairly natural ones, as in the case of the circle.

Comment: In the case of the metric induced from the euclidean $l^2$ norm, what exactly the circle we integrate? Can you give me an example?

Comment: The Fourier series works for periodic functions, which can be imagined as functions in circle. Is there a connection between the two?

Comment: To answer your question "what exactly the circle", the simplest way of putting it is to say that it is the circle parametrized by the angle $\theta$ appearing as $\arccos \alpha\cdot\beta$ as above, as $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$.